# MPMovieController won't dismiss on Done button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mpmoviewcontroller

My movie file starts no problem.  The done button does not dismiss the video content.  No idea why?  Also, Fast Forward and Rewind buttons just cause a black screen.  I don't think I am using the notification functions correctly?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!

@IBAction func videoLaunch(sender: AnyObject) {
    playVideo()
}
func playVideo() {
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyVideo", ofType:"mp4")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
if let player = moviePlayer {
player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen
player.prepareToPlay()
self.view.addSubview(player.view)

}
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "moviePlayBackDidFinish:",
        name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
        object: moviePlayer)


    func moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification){
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding player view as subview. You should remove it (removeFromSuperview) after done button pressed. Use notifications to listen for playback finish:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
self,
selector: "moviePlayBackDidFinish:",
name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
object: moviePlayer)
```

and moviePlayBackDidFinish:

```
func moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification){
  // remove from superview
}
```

Comment: Thanks - How can I add this to the code to listen for the done button being pressed?

Comment: thanks.  Getting error 'use of unresolved identifier' on the object: player line?

Comment: player - is reference to your MPMoviePlayerController. In your case its moviePlayer

Answer (score 1):

You should remove moviePlayer from your superview like this:

```
   func moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification){
        let moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController = notif.object as! MPMoviePlayerController

    moviePlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Because in your case you remove self.view